# Conditionally copy cells to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't worked with VBA for a while and here's what I'm trying to do: I have a worksheet with a column of ID numbers, and then a bunch of columns that make reference to whether the person with that ID has done something ("1") or not ("0"). Something like this:

```
ID     Task1     Task2     Task3
103    1         1         0
129    0         1         0
154    1         1         1
189    1         0         1
204    0         1         1
```

What I want the macro to do is create a new workbook for each Task (and to save the workbook under the name of that Task), and then populate each workbook with only the ID #s of those who have completed the task. So, there should it should create and save workbook called "Task1" which has the values 103, 154, and 189 in column A, create and save a separate workbook called "Task2" which has the values 103, 129, 154, and 204 in column A, and so on.

I haven't been very successful so far. I came up with this:

```
Sub CopyToWorkbooks()
Dim lRow, lCol As Integer

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, "B"), Cells(1, lCol))
    Union(Range("A1:A" & lRow), Range(Cells(1, cell.Column), Cells(lRow, cell.Column))).Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "Users:User:Desktop:WorkbookFolder:" & cell.Value & ".xls" 'For saving the workbook on a Mac
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next cell

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

This successfully creates and save 3 separate workbooks with the correct workbook names, but it copies all of the values in column A and all of the values in the column that corresponds with the new workbook name. So, for example, the workbook "Task2" looks like this:

```
ID     Task2
103    1
129    1
154    1
189    0
204    1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a couple of changes to your code in order to achieve the task you have described:

```
Sub CopyToWorkbooks()
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim lCol As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim tCount As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TaskArr As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Select

    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Loops through each column
    For i = 2 To lCol Step 1
        ReDim TaskArr(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
        tCount = 1
        TaskArr(1, tCount) = ws.Cells(1, 1).Value
        TaskArr(2, tCount) = ws.Cells(1, i).Value
        'Loops through each row
        For j = 2 To lRow Step 1
            If ws.Cells(j, i).Value = 1 Then
                tCount = tCount + 1
                'Read values to array
                ReDim Preserve TaskArr(1 To 2, 1 To tCount)
                TaskArr(1, tCount) = ws.Cells(j, 1).Value
                TaskArr(2, tCount) = ws.Cells(j, i).Value
            End If
        Next j

        'Add new workbook
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Cells(tCount, 2).Address) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TaskArr)
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Users:User:Desktop:WorkbookFolder:" & ws.Cells(1, i).Value & ".xls"     'For saving the workbook on a Mac
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Erase TaskArr
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Instead of copying/pasting the values, I read the values for each task into an array and inserts this into the sheet in the destination workbook.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I tested both the answers provided by Søren and by ZAT and both do the job, but this method runs much faster.

Answer (score 0):

'Below is your posted procedure, ''''''''''appended portion by me'''''''''''

```
Sub CopyToWorkbooks()
Dim lRow, lCol As Integer

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, "B"), Cells(1, lCol))
    Union(Range("A1:A" & lRow), Range(Cells(1, cell.Column), Cells(lRow, cell.Column))).Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "Users:User:Desktop:WorkbookFolder:" & cell.Value & ".xls" 'For saving the workbook on a Mac
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Call FilterSub
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next cell

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

'Below is the procedure to filter the newly created workbooks as per your requirement:

```
Sub FilterSub()
Dim rowNo
Dim cellMatch
Dim pathh
pathh = ActiveWorkbook.Name
With Application.Workbooks(pathh)
rowNo = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set cellMatch = Range("B:B").Find(what:=0)
Do While Not cellMatch Is Nothing
'If cellMatch.Address = "$B$1" Then
'Exit Do
'End If
cellMatch.EntireRow.Delete
Set cellMatch = Range("B:B").FindNext
Loop

Set cellMatch = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```